# Why does OAuth 1.0a require random nonces and how random should they be?

Tags: signature, nonce

[What are the requirements of a nonce?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8495/what-are-the-requirements-of-a-nonce) <- Typically it is only required that a nonce is unique, however, in certain cases harsher requirements (such as randomness and unpredictability) are put.

[The OAuth 1.0a specification states that](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5849#section-3.3):

> A nonce is a random string, uniquely generated by the client to allow
> the server to verify that a request has never been made before and
> helps prevent replay attacks when requests are made over a non-secure
> channel.  The nonce value MUST be unique across all requests with the
> same timestamp, client credentials, and token combinations.

Why does OAuth 1.0a require randomness?

Also I find it surprising that the spec says '*random*' without explicitly requiring cryptographically secure randomness. What could be the benefit of a random, but not cryptographically secure random nonce? I suppose I should understand that the requirement of cryptographically secure randomness is implied here?

Comment: OAuth basically defines a framework on how authentication tokens can be established. It doesn't go deep into security whatsoever. The authentication framework is secure, but only if it gets configured properly. For OAuth 2 there is a separate RFC with security requirements, which is very much needed. Strangely enough, OAuth 1 does specify requirements for the secrets used. Non-secure random RNG's may not be seeded properly (which may not be such a big issue if the RNG is always started with a fresh tim-stamp) and they are fast, but I'd use a large nonce from a well seeded CSPRNG anyway.