# Counter Mode Known plain text attacks

Tags: ctr, known-plaintext-attack, nonce

Counter mode uses a counter that is incremented for each block. Doesnt predictability of this counter expose the scheme to attack? I mean if you are incrementing some nonce, then I have a good chance of guessing the next value

Comment: If you are really paranoid and have doubts about the block cipher to that effect, despite the design criteria of the cipher to resist those attacks, a dual-ctr stream with independent keys masks the ciphertexts so that key recovery should not be possible (under most conditions)

Answer (score 2):

Modern ciphers are explicitly designed to be resistant to key recovery under known and chosen plaintext attacks. Assuming a successful cipher design, encrypting an incrementing counter does not offer an adversary any advantage in regards to obtaining the key, or predicting future ciphertext blocks.

This could be less true with a weak cipher and/or extremely large numbers of encrypted plaintexts.

Comment: why is it then that CBC mode strictly specifies a random IV (sort of a counter that cannot be guessed?). Also, does CTR mode send the initial counter in plain text? -- It seems like this would be the case if guessing the counter is not such a security problem.

Comment: If you use the same IV/key combination twice then security is broken. The IV is normally sent in clear.

Comment: @Minaj CBC and CTR modes work differently and use the IV/nonce for different purposes. [This answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/82/29554) touches upon the subject. Note that while an IV should be unpredictable, it is still known to the adversary because it is sent in the clear. The biggest reason why we dont randomly generate nonce is because collisions happen near the birthday bound, which is too probable for even an 128-bit nonce. If you use a 256 bit nonce you can generate it randomly. Nonce reuse in CTR mode reveals the plaintext, IV reuse in CBC leaks whether 2 blocks are the same.